# Google analytics doesn't populate data with particular metric combination

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have multiple analytics accounts, I am facing problem with one of them. I am trying to fetch data through [Analytics Core Reporting API v3](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/). The metric combination selected are `ga:avgPageLoadTime, ga:users` and for other API call I removed the metric `ga:users`.

For some date ranges I can fetch data when `ga:users` is added to metric combination, but same API call without `ga:users` is not fetching any of the data.

metric combination #1:

`ga:avgPageLoadTime, ga:users`

metric combination #2:

`ga:avgPageLoadTime`

For some date ranges:

The data gets populated for metric combination #1, but gets no data for metric combination #2. Also with metric combination #2. I am also getting data when filtering is added.

Dimension selected is: `ga:deviceCategory`

Comment: Have you considered that there are no users for that date range on that account?  Try running your request here at least you can check that its not your code causing the problem https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/

Comment: Without users how can I get data when users metric is added. And in between data is not shown for only this metric combination.for other combinations and same date range data is seen.

Comment: AvgPageLoadTime is a page-level metric and is not populated for every page on every visit; it is a sampled metric. When mixed with a session-level dimension, if there is no page-level data to report, it could produce an empty report.  Adding the users metric forces a row to be created in the report (zero users will always be reported).